# How to use custom image for Azure Linux Functions in Azure Portal?

Tags: linux, image, azure-functions, customization

May someone have steps to use custom image for Azure Linux Functions in Azure Portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Deploy your Azure Function code in a custom Linux container requires Premium Plan or a Dedicated (App Service Plan) plan hosting.

You can also use default Azure App Service Container

Below are the steps on how to create custom image

- Create a function app and Dockerfile using the Azure Functions Core Tools.
- Build a custom image using Docker.
- Publish a custom image to a container registry.
- Create supporting resources in Azure for the function app
- Deploy a function app from Docker Hub.
- Add application settings to the function app.
- Enable continuous deployment.
- Enable SSH connections to the container.
- Add a Queue storage output binding.

For further information check [Azure Linux Function with Custom Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=in-process,bash,azure-cli&pivots=programming-language-csharp)